# How to get all videos from youtube playlist with youtubeApi for java?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I want to get all videos from youtube playlist, using youtube api for java.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests - Should I use this api version ?
Does it require authentification or can we just use some http request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dude. You can just send http request, like this :
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn&key=AIzaSyCg3WitBUQl5ifC2QygQaZUPOSRMKfSD5E

Comment: so you didn't get all videos, only 50